# My suffix is the pain in the past :'(

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

- My prefix tells you fate has come.
- My suffix is the pain in the past.
- My infix is from the burning sun.
- My whole is American and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not fully sure of my answer, its a long shot with the ‘answers’ to all three -fixes being quite far-fetched but here is my attempt:

You are

> a MUSTANG

My prefix tells you fate has come.

> MUST - Refers to fate being inevitable, it is a must for it to come.

My suffix is the pain in the past.

> STANG - Past tense of sting, so it is the past pain from a sting. (“Stang” is obsolete, so I’m quite uncertain)

My infix is from the burning sun.

> TAN - a golden-brown shade of skin developed by pale-skinned people after exposure to the sun. (or STAN - Slang for a very overzealous fan, one who has a burning passion for his/her idol, so the ‘burning passion’ comes from the burning sun.)

My whole is American and fast.

> MUSTANG - an American feral horse which is typically small and lightly built. (can also be Ford Mustang, series of fast American cars.)

Comment: Zhfg, gna, naq gnat zvtug svg gur pyhrf orggre

Comment: @AmosZoellner Gung znxrf fb zhpu frafr! Lbh fubhyq qrsvavgryl cbfg vg nf na nafjre.

Comment: I was so sure the answer was **NASCAR** (via SC for skin cancer and SCAR for 'pain in the past') that I spent ages trying to work out if [Nas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nas) ever rapped about 'fate' - sadly I couldn't find any decent lyrics which matched up...

Comment: @Stiv NASCAR sure fits most of the clues!